# I can compile my code without getting errors, but it's not working anyways

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(){
    int marks[3];
    printf("enter number for first array");
    scanf("%d",marks[0]);
    printf("enter number for second array");
    scanf("%d",marks[1]);
    printf("enter number for third array");
    scanf("%d",marks[2]);
        printf("the value of first array is %d",marks[0]);
        printf("the value of first array is %d",marks[1]);
        printf("the value of first array is %d",marks[2]);
    return 0;   
}
```

i was expecting that it will print value of matrix but it keeps saying this progarm has unexpectly closed down

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `printf("the value of first array is %d",marks[3]);`, exactly what do you expect this to do, and why? Specifically, where do you expect the value of `marks[3]` to come from? How many elements do you think `marks` should be able to hold, and what do you expect should be the valid indices for that array? (Hint: how many times does your program ask the user for input? How many times does it try to output a different element from the array?)

Comment: Also in `scanf()` a pointer should be passed (e.g. `scanf("%d", &marks[0])`) but you are passing an int.

Comment: You should ask your compiler for more warnings. [I do get diagnostic messages when I try to compile it.](https://godbolt.org/z/KrW9WhT6c)

Comment: Check the man page for `scanf()`. The function returns a value. Your program(s) should ALWAYS check the return value from any system call... Once you've fixed the "address of" problem, run the program and type "foobar" instead of a number... ALWAYS check the return value from functions...

Comment: If `printf("the value of first array is %d",marks[3]);`  was part of your original question (and was not a typo) -- do not edit your question to obfuscate or remove the original code. That provides no benefit to others that may have the same question. Here, the only reference to part of your original problem is found iin a comment comments -- which no longer make sense with the code removed.

Comment: 'I can compile my code without getting errors, but it's not working anyways' - are you aware that is normal behaviour during development?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanf()` expects you to pass the *address* of the variable to fill, eg:

```c
scanf("%d",&marks[0]);
```

`&` is the address-of operator which provides that.

Comment: `scanf()` also expects you will check the return to validate one successful conversion took place (in this case) and absent a successful conversion catch any *matching-failure* or *input-failure* so you can recover prior to your next attempted input.